# Notation in the definition of random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, definition

I am trying to understand definition of random variable.

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P),$ a random variable $X$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to the real numbers $\mathbb R.$ Once the outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ of the experiment is revealed, the corresponding $X(ω)$ is known as realization of the random variable.

Consider two sample spaces $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ and a sigma-algebra $\mathcal F_2$ of sets in $\Omega_2.$ Then, for $X$ to be a random variable, there must exist a sigma-algebra $\mathcal F_1$ in $Ω_1$ such that for any set $S$ in $\mathcal F_2$ the inverse image of $S,$ defined by:

$$X^{-1}(S) := \{ω \mid X(ω) ∈ S\}$$

I do not know how to read this and I am hoping some one can explain each part to me.

Comment: It's just the preimage of a subset of the reals on the r.v. It's set theoretic notation.

Comment: ω | X(ω) ∈ S how does this read? Is X a random variable or a function? Does it read Given realization of ω using the function X belongs to a subset S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be pertinent to frame the answer defining a random variable as a measurable function $X$ from the sample space of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ to the space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ of the real numbers endowed with the Borel sigma algebra (i.e. the smallest sigma algebra which contains the open sets of $\mathbb R$), such that

$$X^{-1}(A)=\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega)\in A\}\in \mathcal F \;\; \forall A \in \mathcal B.$$

Constructing the sigma-field (or sigma-algebra) generated by two random variables will bring home the idea as follows:

The random experiment is tossing a fair die once, which has as possible outcomes or sample space $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

It is up to the definition of the probability space to determine which events will have assigned probabilities. We could consider the events **even or odd outcome** and contrapose it to the events **prime or not-prime**. Thus we define two random variables: $X: \Omega \to \{0,1\}$ maps the outcome to $1$ if the die lands on an odd number, and otherwise $0.$ On the other hand, the second random variable $Y: \Omega\to \{0,1\}$ maps to $1$ when the die lands on a prime number.

Now these two random variables will generate two different sigma algebras. In the first case, the pre-image of the random variable $X$ will include the set $V=\{1,3,5\}$ corresponding to the value of the random variable $1$ in the Borel set $A_1=\{1\}:$

$$V=X^{-1}(A_1)=\{\omega\in\Omega \mid X(\omega) \in A_1\}=\{1,3,5\}$$

This reads: The pre-image (not the inverse function!) of the set $A_1$ for the random variable $X$ is the set $\{\text{...}\}$ containing those outcomes ($\omega$) in the big set $\Omega$ such that (that is the little bar $\mid$) the random variable maps to elements in $A_1.$ And the fact that $\{1,3,5\}\in \mathcal F$ (see below) makes the function $X$ measurable.

Logically, there would be the set $W =\{2,4,6\}$ corresponding to the pre-image of the value $0$ in the Borel set $ A_2=\{0\},$ or

$$W=X^{-1}(A_2)=\{\omega\in\Omega \mid X(\omega) \in A_2\}=\{2,4,6\}$$

The sigma algebra will also contain complementary, union and finite intersections, ending up with the sigma algebra $\mathcal F=\{\{1,3,5\} , \{2,4,6\}, \emptyset,\Omega \},$ of which $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{2,4,6\}$ are called atoms (an atom of $\mathcal F$ is a set $F \in \mathcal F$ such that the only subsets of $F$ which are also in $\mathcal F$ are the empty set $\emptyset$ and $F$ itself). And the probability space will determine (in a fair die) that $\frac12$ is assigned to each one of them by the PMF: $\mathbb P\left(\{1,3,5\}\in \mathcal F\right )= \sum_{\mathbf 1_{1,3,5}} p(\omega_i )=3\frac 1 6.$

Here is the construct:

[image]

All Borel sets of interest have pre-images corresponding to sets in the sigma algebra $\mathcal F.$

If instead the events of interest were **powers of 2** and **powers of 3**, the sigma algebra would contain $\small \left\{\emptyset, \Omega,\{1,2,4\},\{3,5,6\},\{1,3\},\{2,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,3,5,6\},\{1,2,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4,5,6\}\right\}$, the function simply mapping the face of the die to the numbers $1,\dots,6$ would not be a random variable, because the set formed by the pre-image of the singleton Borel set $\small \{5\}$ is not in the sigma algebra (not measurable): $\small \text{pre-image}(\{5\})=\{5\}\notin \mathcal F$.

Going back to the random variable $X,$ i.e. (odd, even), it will not contain information allowing separation of $1$ from $3$ for example, because they are both outcomes belonging to the same event ("odd").

The same exercise for $Y$ will result in two atomic sets $\{2,3,5\}$ and $\{1,4,6\},$ and a sigma algebra $\mathcal G=\{\{2,3,5\} , \{1,4,6\}, \emptyset,\Omega \}.$

This random variable $Y,$ in contradistinction to $X,$ contains information allowing us to separate the outcomes $1$ and $3.$

Comment: Brillant answer! The examples are so clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probability notation can be a bit confusing at first! Maybe a simple example helps to see why the notation is actually chosen in a somewhat natural way:

Let's look at a specific probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ that corresponds to the toss of a coin. So the sample space is $\Omega = \{H, T\}$, where we denote 'Heads' by $H$ and 'Tails' by $T$. We set $F = 2^\Omega$ and we're looking at a fair coin toss, so $P(H) = P(T) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now we define the random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, X(H) = 0, X(T) = 1$. You can think of the r.v. $X$ as doing an 'experiment', in this case tossing the coin, and recording a $0$ for 'Heads' and a $1$ for 'Tails'. Now of course your question is, "What is the probability that my experiment results in a Heads?". So, linguistically you would want to write something like:

$$P(X = 0) = \frac{1}{2}$$

This is why we define it exactly this way:

$$P(X = 0) := P(X^-1(\{0\})) = P(\{\omega | X(\omega) = 0\})\, (= P(H) = \frac{1}{2})$$

We have to do it like this, because the probability measure $P$ 'lives' on the left-hand side (the $\Omega$-side) and can only measure things there, but the outcomes of the experiment 'live' on the right-hand side.

I hope this doesn't confuse more than it helps...

Comment: Does {} denote subset here? P(H) (probability of heads) = P(X=0) = P(X−1({0})) (probability of coin toss result yeilding X(w) = 0)?

Comment: yes, everything with the curly brackets {} is a set. So $X^-1(\{0\})$ is the preimage of the (sub-)set {0} ($\subseteq \mathbb{R}$) under the random variable $X$, so all elements $\omega$ in $\Omega$ such that $X(\omega) = 0$. The last sentence is just the same as $\{\omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) = 0\}$, which is of course also a set.